# ABAddressBook poor performance since iOS 6

Tags: ios5, ios6, abaddressbook, performance

i have a App that imports round about 12000 numbers in 3 contacts and 1 group. Since iOS 6 this process needs 5 times longer than before with iOS 5.1. In the simulator it isn't as slow as on a device.

I tried some profiling and I found out that the main time is used by ABAddressBookSave with 28% of execution time. I also got the feeling that everything with Addressbook is slower than before. On iOS 5 its about 3% of the total execution time. Memory and CPU are ok.

Has anyone had similar problems, did anyone find out why this happens or discover a solution to fix it?

**Here is a stackTrace. Why is it so slow in iOS 6?**

Running Time    Self        Symbol Name
3212.0ms   41.6%    0,0       ABAddressBookSave

3212.0ms   41.6%    0,0        ABCSave

3212.0ms   41.6%    0,0         ABCAddressBookSaveWithConflictPolicy

3198.0ms   41.4%    0,0          CPRecordStoreSaveWithPreAndPostCallbacksAndTransactionType

3134.0ms   40.6%    0,0           CFDictionaryApplyFunction

3134.0ms   40.6%    0,0            CFBasicHashApply

3134.0ms   40.6%    0,0             __CFDictionaryApplyFunction_block_invoke_0

3134.0ms   40.6%    0,0              CPRecordStoreUpdateRecord

2971.0ms   38.5%    0,0               _didSave

2971.0ms   38.5%    0,0                ABCDContextUpdateSearchIndexForPersonAndProperties

2773.0ms   35.9%    0,0                 CPSqliteStatementPerform

2773.0ms   35.9%    0,0                  sqlite3_step

2773.0ms   35.9%    0,0                   sqlite3VdbeExec

2772.0ms   35.9%    0,0                    fts3UpdateMethod

2765.0ms   35.8%    0,0                     fts3PendingTermsAdd

2734.0ms   35.4%    0,0                      ABCFFTSTokenizerOpen

2734.0ms   35.4%    0,0                       ABTokenListPopulateFromString

2631.0ms   34.1%    1,0                        CFStringGetBytes

2630.0ms   34.1%    2624,0                          __CFStringEncodeByteStream

6.0ms    0.0%   0,0                          CFStringEncodingIsValidEncoding

**And here the same method in iOS 5**

Running Time    Self        Symbol Name

245.0ms   12.9% 0,0     ABAddressBookSave

245.0ms   12.9% 0,0      ABCSave

245.0ms   12.9% 0,0       ABCAddressBookSaveWithConflictPolicy

234.0ms   12.3% 0,0        CPRecordStoreSaveWithPreAndPostCallbacksAndTransactionType

167.0ms    8.8% 0,0         CFDictionaryApplyFunction

167.0ms    8.8% 0,0          CFBasicHashApply

167.0ms    8.8% 0,0           __CFDictionaryApplyFunction_block_invoke_0

167.0ms    8.8% 0,0            CPRecordStoreUpdateRecord

162.0ms    8.5% 0,0             CFDictionaryApplyFunction

162.0ms    8.5% 0,0              CFBasicHashApply

162.0ms    8.5% 0,0               __CFDictionaryApplyFunction_block_invoke_0

162.0ms    8.5% 0,0                CPRecordStoreSaveProperty

158.0ms    8.3% 0,0                 ABCMultiValueSave

158.0ms    8.3% 1,0                  ABCDBContextSaveMultiValue

143.0ms    7.5% 0,0                   CPSqliteConnectionAddRecord

143.0ms    7.5% 1,0                    CPSqliteConnectionAddRecordWithRowid

85.0ms    4.5%  0,0                     CPSqliteStatementPerform

16.0ms    0.8%  2,0                     CFRelease